# Getting clean urls with .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been going nuts at this with clean urls for some time now and i was hoping to get some assistance here with some tips and hopefully a solution.

**Update**

Here's my current navigation @anubhava

```
$select_category = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE hidden = 0 ORDER BY menu ASC");
while ($ln = mysql_fetch_array($select_category)) {
  $idcat = $ln['nmr'];
  $catname = $ln['menu'];
  $catsname = str_replace(' ', '-', $ln['menu']);

  echo '<li>';
  if($catname == "a certain category"){
  echo '<a href="http://mywebsite.aurl.net/" title="'.$catname.'"><span><strong>'.$catname.'</strong></span></a>'. PHP_EOL;
     }else{
  echo '<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/cats/'.$idcat.'/'.$catsname.'/" title="'.$catname.'"><span><strong>'.$catname.'</strong></span></a>'. PHP_EOL; // if the user press on a main category it will stay open using GET[] on $idcat in categorymain.php
     }
  echo '<ul';


  if(isset($_GET['cats']) && $_GET['cats'] == $idcat){
    echo ' style="display:block;">'. PHP_EOL;
  }else{
    echo '>'. PHP_EOL;
  }

  $select_sub = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM submenu WHERE nmrmenu = '$idcat' AND hidden = 0");
  while ($lsub = mysql_fetch_array($select_sub)) {
      $subname = $lsub['submenu'];
    $subsname = str_replace(' ', '-', $lsub['submenu']);
    $pil = '&raquo;';
    $brnr = $lsub['nmr'];

    if(isset($_GET['cat'])){
    if ($_GET['cat'] == $brnr){
        $subname = '<u>'.$lsub['submenu'].'</u>'; // here the subcategory gets underlined if the user press on a sub category in category.php

    }else{
        $subname = $lsub['submenu'];
    }
    }

    echo '<li><a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/cat/'.$lsub['nmr'].'/'.$idcat.'/'.$subsname.'/"><span><strong> '.$pil.' '.$subname.' </strong></span></a></li>'. PHP_EOL; // here i send both main and sub category id so i can keep the main category opened and the underlined sub category when a user has pressed it.
  }

  echo '</ul>'. PHP_EOL;
  echo '</li>'. PHP_EOL;
   }
```

**/update**

**Currently my code in htaccess look like this:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} cats/(.*)/
RewriteRule ^cats/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(.*)/$ /categorymain.php?cats=$1&mcn=$2
```

Which displays like this: www.xxxxx.com/cats/x/the_main_category/ and it's not very nice.

My goal is: www.xxxxx.com/the_main_category/

**And i even got this:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} cat/(.*)/
RewriteRule ^cat/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /category.php?cat=$1&cats=$2&cn=$3
```

Which displays like this: www.xxxxx.com/cat/x/x/the_sub_category/ and it's really not nice.

My goal is: www.xxxxx.com/the_sub_category/

**Lastly i've got this really horrible line:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} id/(.*)/
RewriteRule ^id/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /product.php?id=$1&cat=$2&cats=$3&pn=$4
```

Which displays like this: www.xxxxxx.com/id/xxxx/x/x/the_product/  *horrid* :O

My goal is: www.xxxxx.com/the_product/

I would be incredibly happy if you could help me solve this issue

The reason for so many variables is because i use them in the navigation so the users easily can see where they are in the e-store if they want to go back, also a "internal" navigation above the categories and products so they don't have to use the side navigation more than necessary.

Comment: Do you understand, that you'll have to change the scripts, if you want to use these short urls, because you won't get ids?

Comment: @user4035 Yes, i am aware of this. But im not exactly sure which way to go since i view the categories and products based on the ID. But for optimization i need to have the names in there.

Comment: For the URL that you want: `www.xxxxx.com/the_product/` what do you want it to be rewritten to?

Comment: @anubhava My goal is for it to be what you wrote. Currently it is: www.xxxxxx.com/id/xxxx/x/x/the_product/

Comment: I understand the pretty URL you want i.e. `www.xxxxx.com/the_product/` but what you want it to become internally?

Comment: @anubhava Internally i kind of need it to be like it is now to use the user follow system(for the navigation) or i'll have to change follow system in some way. But to use the current one it has to look like the example. so basically: `product.php?id=the_product_id&cat=the_sub_cat_id&cats=the_main_cat_id&pn=the_product_name` Perhaps i've understood you wrong with "internally" then give me a heads up and i'll try to find you another answer :)

Comment: See original URI is: `/the_product/` so we can only use `the_product` as dynamic value in rewritten URI like `/product.php?id=the_product/` but rest of the values like `cat_id, sub_cat_id` will be missing.

Comment: @anubhava The problem with this is that some product names have signs in them so the sql can't find them for some reason. That's why i have to use the product article nubmer(pno) e.g: `product.php?id=$id&pn=$prodname` and unfortunately there is too many products to change the signs or add another column for "seo". It's a possible solution, but the client won't let me take that time.

Comment: @anubhava I can keep the id in the url for the products and also for the categories, but my biggest problem is to get rid of the `.com/id/<--- this one` because then my `GET['id']` is false. Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Your last comment was bit confusing: `I can keep the id in the url for the products and also for the categories, but my biggest problem is to get rid of the .com/id` IMO you must keep id in URI like Satckoverflow URLs

Comment: @anubhava Lets take flickr for example: `http://flickr.com/users.php?id=username&page=2 ` Gets like: `http://flickr.com/username/2` this is what i am after. They don't have `http://flickr.com/id/username/2`. You understand what i mean?

Comment: Yes but `http://flickr.com/username/2` still have `id` as 2 and that you can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /product.php?id=$2&pn=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

This will support URI structure as: `/productname/123` to be internally rewritten as `/product.php?id=123&pn=productname`

Comment: Thanks man, it works! Now I'll have to rewrite the entire navigation system to use something else than get variables so the users can keep track of where they are in the web shop. I keep the navigation they click on open based on a get variable so they easily can change sub category under the same main category and the sub category they click on get a underline so they easily can go back to the same category and choose a different product. You got any ideas on what i could do for that one?

Comment: Can you provide an example of that since I got confused again.

Comment: I use `$_GET[]` variables in categorymain.php and in category.php to keep the navigation open when a user has clicked on a maincategory and making the subcategory underlined when they have clicked on a subcategory. lets say they click on Volvo(main) and then click on S40(sub) The main will stay open because i always have the "parent" main_id in the url and the other mains closed. And S40 will get underscored because i have the sub_id in the url and the other subs will not be underscored.

Comment: So if i then change the url as we've done for the products i exclude the id's in the url, which will not keep the subs underscored and the main wont stay open once the sub is clicked. ^_^

Comment: Have a call to attend, will be back in 30 mins.

Comment: `So if i then change the url as we've done for the products` What URL are you trying for this category/sub-category?

Comment: I want it to be the same as for the product, and i know how to do it using the code you provided earlier. But if i make it look like that for both main and sub categories the main category wont stay open if a sub category is clicked and the sub category wont be underscored when clicked. So i am looking for a different way than `GET[]` variables to make the main category stay open and the sub category stay underscored if clicked. For easy navigation purposes as a user.

Comment: GET variable is the only way rewrite rules can pass this info. But via php you can keep this data on session or cookie.

Comment: But if i store it as a session, won't it add one id to the session each time a category is clicked, making the navigation have several categories open at once?

Comment: Just one more question even though it is answered. If i want to use the rewrite rule for lets say both product.php, maincategory.php and category.php? I've tried adding the same rule to these php files, but they count them as products.

Comment: Yes because URI matching pattern `^([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$` is same for all of them. I suggest using some prefix like `^m-([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$` for maincategory and `^c-([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$` for category.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what you're going to need is a "slug" which is a unique identifier string for each category. If the category name is "Food Stuff", your unique slug would need to be "food-stuff" for the URL. Once you've established these unique slugs, change your script to look up by slug `&cat=food-stuff` rather than by the ID in the database.

From here its rather trivial, you can just use your rewrite rules and accomplish your desired result.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)/
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(.*)/$ /categorymain.php?cats=$1&mcn=$2
```

Comment: Currently I'm using the product name and replacing all the spaces with - signs to get it look better. What i suppose you mean is to put a column in the database for each product with this function already in place so all i have to do is call that one instead of the id? The problem i see with this is that i have more than 40 000 products in the store.

Comment: I've been trying your idea (minus the slug) for some time now but it doesn't seem to work as supposed. I have to enter `www.xxxx.com/id <-- this/xxx(pno)/the_product` or i will get a 404. Do you know what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you really need is to simply pass everything to a single location:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

You would then parse the requested URL in PHP and determine whether a main category, sub category, or product was requested (by comparing to a database or the like).

I understand you want "clean" URLs, but restricting your URLs to just text will only work if each main category, sub category, and product name is unique, which most certainly is not realistic.  Your original design /some_id/some_name/ is perfectly fine.  Having a number in the URL doesn't make it "unclean."

Comment: The main and sub categories have equal id's in some places hence the auto increment. The product list is based on article number(unique), no auto increment. All the products have unique names of course since i don't have the same product twice. But basically what you mean is that i should move all product data, main category data, and subcategory data into the index.php and doing checks inside that file to get my desired effect?

Comment: I can actually change the categories to have different id's in the database to make everything unique. But the issue i get is that i use a get variable to collect the ID, `.com/id/ <--- i want to get rid of this one` But then it can't show my products because `GET['id']` is false. Do you have a solution for this?